# pass variable to function using same name

Tags: php

Is it considered wrong to pass a variable to a function where the variable passed has the same name as the variable in the function itself? I never see anyone do this, but wondered if there was a reason why (other than readability). Example:

```
$variable = "value";

function myFunction($variable) {
    return $variable;
}
```

Comment: No, inside the function `$variable` is the param you passed, not the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not problem with doing this except some naming confusion. Because,

```
$variable = "value"; // this declaration belong to a global scope

// but $variable passing through as argument, makes it scope within that function declaration only
function myFunction($variable) {
    return $variable;
}
```

You might have expect that if you call the function like `myFunction()` i.e. without any parameter, it will return you "value", but absolutely not, cause `$variable` passed as argument is not the global one.

But if you try to use the global `$variable` within the `myFunction`, then it will cause some conflict, that is why no one do this.

Comment: I think the more common way of avoiding that conflict in modern applications is to never use global variables, at which point you can give variables whatever name makes sense for the scope they're in.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making variables a bit confusing to track, there is nothing wrong with this. They exist in different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you but vice versa, if you want to pass intentionally a variable into a function.. then you have to use this:

```
$variable = "value";

function myFunction($variable) {
global $variable;
return $variable;
}

echo myFunction('another value');
```

One more point. When creating functions you may set a default value for your params to avoid errors:

```
function myFunction($variable="default value") {
return $variable;
}

echo myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with it at all, and I would have thought it's quite common.

However, you should always be choosing the best name for a variable, or a parameter, in each situation, not applying one rule to your whole code.

For instance, in a database lookup function, it might be obvious what `$id` refers to, so it would be a sensible parameter name; but where you are calling it, you will likely have lots of IDs of various sorts, so a more descriptive variable name should be used. On the other hand, each time you build an SQL string, it's probably the only such variable in scope, so giving it a consistent name keeps your code tidy and easy to read.

A common observation is that all code is read more often than it is written (yes, even your personal website that you wouldn't dare share with the world). Variable names should be chosen with that in mind: what makes this code easy to read, understand, and maintain?

Answer (score -2):

You can use global and add default value in param variable.

```
$variable = "value";
function myFunction($variable = '') {
        global $variable;
    return $variable;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you think this does, but all you have there is an unused function parameter.